# The simplest demonstration of convergence / divergence of $(a^{n^\alpha})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that $a$ is a strictly positive real number.

The question is to study convergence/divergence of the real series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^{n^\alpha}$$ depending on the value of $\alpha$.

I can do it. I'm looking for the sharpest / simplest arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a\ge1\Rightarrow\sum a^{n^\alpha}\ge\sum 1\\
\alpha\ge1,a<1\Rightarrow\sum a^{n^\alpha}\le\sum a^n={1\over1-a}\\
\alpha<0,a<1\Rightarrow\lim a^{n^\alpha}=\lim a^{1\over n^{-\alpha}}=a^0=1\Rightarrow\sum a^{n^\alpha}=\infty\\$$
For $0<\alpha,a<1$ we can use limit comparison test using the convergent series $\sum{1\over n^2}$$$\lim n^2(a^{n^\alpha})=\lim n^2\exp(n^\alpha\ln(a))\
=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{2\over\alpha}\exp(\ln(a)x)=0\\ 
\because\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{p}\exp(-qx)=0\;\forall p,q>0\land\ln(a)<0\\
\therefore\sum{a^{n^\alpha}}<\infty$$